# How to set the properties of a file to 0777?

Tags: php

How can I set the properties of a file to 0777 which i created through php create file?

```
$myFile = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = 'test';
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php Is this what your looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0777);
```

according to: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.chmod.php

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

You have 2 alternatives - to set it after with [chmod()](http://nz.php.net/chmod) or use [umask()](http://nz.php.net/umask) before. In the latter case you need to restore it back to not break other code, that relies on the original umask value (if any).

Answer (score 1):

You can protect your file using chmod. Here is an example:

```
chmod($myFile, 0777);
```

Take a look at [`chmod`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php).